# ¿Como darle una ruta al JFileChooser sin importar?

Tags: java, netbeans

Resulta que estoy tratando de exportar una imagen, esta imagen se ubica dentro de la carpeta del proyecto, y resulta que al momento de tratar de exportar la imagen, la unica forma es por medio del JFileChooser(lo hago por medio de la interfaz).

```
        String gh="direccion.png";//Ruta de la imagen
        File img=new File(gh);
        JFileChooser destino= new JFileChooser();
        File ruta= destino.getSeletedFile();//Esto es lo que permite exportar
```

Lo único que necesito saber es ¿como darle la ruta al JFileChooser para poder exportar la imagen?
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando un JFileChooser ¿Por qué no dejarle al usa el programa elegir la ruta en la que quiere exportar el archivo?

JFileChooser sirve para eso mismo, abre una ventana donde puedes elegir un archivo o una ruta destino.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para exportar solo debes obtener la ruta seleccionada

```
File target = chooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Y copiar la imagen en esa ruta. (source es el archivo imagen)

```
try {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Un ejemplo simple al código que tienes seria:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    
    int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(null); // parent
    
    File source = new File("direccion.png");
    File target = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    
    if(option != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION || target == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    try {
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

A JFileChooser no le puedes dar una ruta mediante código que apunte al archivo que deseas, esto no tendría sentido ya que bien podrías crear un File con la ruta destino y directamente copiar la imagen.

Lo que si se puede hacer es especificar desde que ubicación se abrirá y mostrara los archivos para seleccionar:

```
new JFileChooser("/home/user/Escritorio"); // desde aquí se mostraran los archivos
```

También decir que usar un selector de archivos no es la única forma, bien puedes copiar un archivo de un lugar a otro sin necesidad de usarlo, mientras tengas un archivo y una ruta destino puedes copiarlo en ese lugar.

Si tienes alguna duda o pregunta de lo que he escrito no dudes en decirlo ya que puede esté equivocado en lo que hace la función "exportar".